# An interval with width greater than one contains an integer.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have an interval $(a, b)$ such that $b - a > 1$, how can I prove that this contains an integer? It seems 'obvious', but a formal proof eludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\,n\,$ be the least integer $\,\ge b.\ $ Then consider  $\,n-1.$